# Powershell doesnt script filtered indexes

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

I am trying to script my database definitions (tables,indexes,triggers, ...) with powershell into .sql files. Until now it was working well.

Recently we started using filtered indexes in our SQL Server 2008 database. These indexes are scripted without the WHERE-clause.

If i try to generate the script within the MS SQL Server Management Studio

with either "right click on index - script as - create index" or "tasks - generate scripts"

it is working.

I have read a a few bug reports that concerning filtered indexes here https://sqlblog.org/2011/05/16/connect-digest-2011-05-16 but I am not sure if they apply to my problem.

Any Advice?

Answer (score 0):

Scripting filtered indexes works fine for me. Here's some test code you can try:

Create a filtered index using the Adventworks (from BOL example):

```
USE AdventureWorks2008R2;
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.indexes
    WHERE name = N'FIBillOfMaterialsWithEndDate' 
    AND object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'Production.BillOfMaterials'))
DROP INDEX FIBillOfMaterialsWithEndDate
    ON Production.BillOfMaterials;
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX "FIBillOfMaterialsWithEndDate"
    ON Production.BillOfMaterials (ComponentID, StartDate)
    WHERE EndDate IS NOT NULL;
GO
```

Using sqlps navigate to the index container for the Production.BillOfMaterials table:

```
cd SQLSERVER:\SQL\WIN7BOOT\SQL1\Databases\AdventureWorks\Tables\Production.BillOfMaterials\indexes
```

Get the FIBillOfMaterialsWithEndDate index and script it:

```
get-item FIBillOfMaterialsWithEndDate | foreach {$_.script()};
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [FIBillOfMaterialsWithEndDate] ON [Production].[BillOfMaterials]
(
        [ComponentID] ASC,
        [StartDate] ASC
)
WHERE ([EndDate] IS NOT NULL)
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
 ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```